# How to show default app screen when my application is in recent app list screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am creating a messaging application, this contain the passcode function. When the passcode is turn on, I would like to show my application's default picture in recent app list. How can I do for this?

I currently used the

```
getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

This show blank screen in recent app list but don't allow to take the screenshot while running application. And I cannot show my application's default screen instead of blank screen.

Is there any other ways?

I already tried to override onPause() method and change to blank UI before running the onPause() method, this cannot change the app image that show in recent app list screen.(app list screen cannot show the latest state of my application. May be onPause() is too late for change)

Please give me suggestion. Thanks.